# Arp packet or range IP

Tags: c, arp

Good evening. I’m writing a small program in C, which should get the mac addresses of all active devices from the IP range 192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255 (the command line cannot be used). Display the result on the console ip = mac. To solve the problem, an ARP request was chosen. How advisable is it to use it? Will I be able to get the mac address of a subnet that I am not in? My C code unfortunately does not output anything. Help me please

```
#include<linux/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256


struct arp_header {
    uint16_t hardware_type;
    uint16_t protocol_type;
    uint8_t hardware_len;
    uint8_t protocol_len;
    uint16_t opcode;
    uint8_t sender_mac[6];
    uint8_t sender_ip[4];
    uint8_t target_mac[6];
    uint8_t target_ip[4];

};

void create_arp_request(uint8_t *sender_mac, uint8_t *sender_ip, uint8_t *target_ip, uint8_t *packet) {
    // Fill Ethernet header
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) packet;
    uint8_t broadcast_mac[6] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
    memcpy(eth->h_dest, broadcast_mac, ETH_ALEN); // Destination MAC address (broadcast)
    memcpy(eth->h_source, sender_mac, ETH_ALEN); // Source MAC address
    eth->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_ARP); // ARP frame type

    // Fill ARP header
    struct arp_header arp;
    memset(&arp, 0, sizeof(struct arp_header));
    arp.hardware_type = htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
    arp.protocol_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    arp.hardware_len = ETH_ALEN;
    arp.protocol_len = sizeof(in_addr_t);
    arp.opcode = htons(ARPOP_REQUEST);
    memcpy(arp.sender_mac, sender_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy(arp.sender_ip, sender_ip, sizeof(in_addr_t));
    memset(arp.target_mac, 0, ETH_ALEN); // Target MAC address (unknown)
    memcpy(arp.target_ip, target_ip, sizeof(in_addr_t));

    // Copy ARP header to packet array
    memcpy(packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr), &arp, sizeof(struct arp_header));
}

void receive_arp_responses(int socket_fd, uint8_t *sender_ip) {
    while (1) {
        uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        struct sockaddr_ll recvaddr;
        socklen_t recvaddrlen = sizeof(recvaddr);

        // Wait for data reception
        ssize_t packet_len = recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &recvaddr,
                                      &recvaddrlen);

        // Check for reception error
        if (packet_len == -1) {
            perror("Failed to receive packet");
            break;
        }

        // Get Ethernet and ARP headers
        struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) buffer;
        struct arp_header *arp = (struct arp_header *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

        // Check if the received packet is an ARP response and the sender IP matches the target IP
        if (ntohs(eth->h_proto) == ETH_P_ARP &&
            memcmp(arp->sender_ip, sender_ip, 4) == 0 &&
            ntohs(arp->opcode) == ARPOP_REPLY) {
            // Print information about the ARP response
            printf("ARP Response received:\n");
            printf("Sender MAC: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", arp->sender_mac[0], arp->sender_mac[1],
                   arp->sender_mac[2], arp->sender_mac[3], arp->sender_mac[4], arp->sender_mac[5]);
            printf("Sender IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", arp->sender_ip[0], arp->sender_ip[1], arp->sender_ip[2],
                   arp->sender_ip[3]);

            // Additional processing of the received ARP response

        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int delay = 1;
    uint8_t packet[sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct arp_header)];

    int socket_fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (socket_fd == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    // Specify the listening interface
    struct sockaddr_ll sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    sa.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sa.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ARP);
    sa.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("eth0");

    // Bind the socket to the interface
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to bind socket");
        close(socket_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create ARP request
    uint8_t sender_mac[6] = {0xC5, 0xA6, 0x93, 0x5A, 0x9E, 0xQS}; // Sender MAC address
    uint8_t sender_ip[4] = {192, 168, 0, 101}; // Sender IP address

    // Send ARP request for a range of target IP addresses
    for (int i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        uint8_t target_ip[4] = {192, 168, 0, i}; // Iterate over IP address range
        create_arp_request(sender_mac, sender_ip, target_ip, packet);
        int num_bytes = sendto(socket_fd, packet, sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct ether_arp), 0,
                               (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        // Send ARP request
        if (sendto(socket_fd, packet, sizeof(packet), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
            perror("Failed to send ARP request");
            close(socket_fd);
            return 1;
        }
        sleep(delay);
    }
    receive_arp_responses(socket_fd, sender_ip);
    close(socket_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not your problem, but this block is not correct: `// Fill ARP header` You cannot rely on `packet` being properly aligned for accessing all the non-character members of that struct. `uint8_t packet[...];` This is possible to start on an address not suitable for accessing `uint16_t` members (yet, this is rather unlikely)

Comment: I'm not getting any console output right now. I tried changing it, but that's not the problem

Comment: I am confused about iteration over the ip range. I would think you just need to use mac broadcast address , and send it to network 192.168.0.0/16 or something. You iterate up to 100 (i understand 101 is your machine). Are there machines in range 1 - 100 or maybe thery are all above?

Comment: on linux, wireshark is a great tool to debug what is being sent over the network, and whether there are responses sent or not

Comment: so you can debug whether packets are sent, are they correct, are there responses and do you listen for them correctly or is problem there

Comment: now i remember why you iterate over the range. my bad for earlier not smart  comment. Just make sure there are machines in that range, but still: wireshark should be of great help here

Comment: A small range up to 101 for a test to quickly check whether I am receiving responses to the ARP request. In the future, yes, there should be a range 192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255. I don’t use whireshark because I want to write the data to the database later. But first, the output to the console

Comment: Is it also possible that the problem is that I’m using an Apple Mac M1 -> I’m running the project in docker? The code compiles without errors. But there is no output to the console

Comment: ARP is not routed. It will only work on the local subnet.

Comment: whireshark doesn't show that I'm sending arp

Comment: Is there an option to send ARP to another subnet?

Comment: wireshark should show this, at least if it is not filtered out. Maybe datal ink layer is turned off by default, try enabling it, maybe showing only ARP packets. You could potentially do any web stuff (like going to some webpage or using `ping`) to see if ARP packets are generated and compare them to yours (if yours are sent)

Comment: whireshark shows the data but my ARP send is not => I mean there is a bug in the code. But I can't find her

Comment: why are therre two `sendto`s? i will admit i never worked with packet sockets so maybe it is ok, but i do not understand what they do

Comment: Fixed the bug. There is still no output to the console

Comment: so you see sent arp in wireshark?
what was the bug?

Comment: I was wrong, it's not my sent packets that whireshark shows. The code requires corrections. But what kind